# Cross Browswer Device Fingerprinting Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, fingerprinting

I want to avoid 2F authentication if the user is logging in from the same device he has logged in before. This should be independent of the browser he is using.

I have looked at ClientJs and FingerprintJs2. However I am looking for a better way to identify the device. This should be quick enough to have a good user experience.

Comment: Better way than what? What is the actual programming problem here? It looks like you're searching for some external resources ..?

Comment: Yes. These two give some uniqueness across browsers but I am looking for more. Any best practices or standards !!